# Join table multiple possibility choose one sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, merge

I have two tables that I want to join, the problem is a one to many relation.

I have in table 1 a column called gender which is either 1 or 2. Now I want to join that with table two, which is a one to many relation and want it to join with the English description.

[image: what i have]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking
update your question add that the related  tables schema a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: I don't see an obvious relation betweens those two tables.  Please update your question and include cleanly formatted tables showing the sample data.  Just doing this might allow you to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: If you join on the gender you'd need to add a `WHERE LanguageId = 1` condition. Alternatively `INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.GenderId = T2.GenderId AND LanguageId = 1` depending on your query structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the `language` number in your join condition.

```
select t1.*, t2.Representation
from t1
  inner join t2
    on t1.Gender=t2.Gender
   and t2.Language=1
```

Or if you have a third table that tells you which language corresponds to the number in `language`:

```
select t1.*, t2.Representation
from t1
  inner join t2
    on t1.Gender=t2.Gender
  inner join t3
    on t2.Language=t3.Language
where t3.LanguageName = 'English'
```